Azure DevOps Extension - Error occured in Rule Engine Evaluate
I am currently developing an extension for Azure Boards and am getting the following error message:
ms.vss-work-web.work…es6.CHv17_.min.js:1 
Error: Error occured in Rule Engine Evaluate. Name: undefined Message: Node not found:extension_dev\Sprint 1 Rules.length: 2 Rules.Information: Block,Computed,-104,Trigger,-104 Stack: Error: Node not found:extension_dev\Sprint 1
    at i.validate (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:46504)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:37157)
    at t.<computed>.RuleEngine._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:49623)
    at ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:49907
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.<computed>.RuleEngine._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:49860)
    at t.<computed>.RuleEngine.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:48959)
    at i.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:142335)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:142219)
    at i.load (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:152699)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:37345)
    at t.<computed>.RuleEngine._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:49623)
    at ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:49907
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.<computed>.RuleEngine._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:49860)
    at t.<computed>.RuleEngine.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work…v17_.min.js:1:48959)
    at i.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:142335)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:142219)
    at i.load (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:152699)
    at new i (ms.vss-work-web.work…17_.min.js:1:121465)

I am not quite sure what to do with this, as I haven't changed any rules and have only recently been getting this error message. I have been trying to find what caused this, but without any luck. Any ideas what could have caused this, or how to fix it?
EDIT (added info and MRE):
When I started developing my extension I was mostly following the official documentation and this.
MRE of my main files:
page.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>

page.tsx:
import * as React from "react";
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
import "azure-devops-ui/Core/override.css";
import { showRootComponent } from "../Common";
import { Page } from "azure-devops-ui/Page"

export class MainComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  public async componentDidMount() {
    await SDK.init();
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <Page className="main-component flex-grow">
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

showRootComponent(<MainComponent />);

package.json
{
  "name": "<publisher>-ado-extension-dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist ./out",
    "compile": "npm run clean && webpack --mode development",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "package": "npm run compile && tfx extension create --manifest-globs vss-extension.json --output-path out --rev-version"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "azure-devops-extension-api": "^4.235.0",
    "azure-devops-extension-sdk": "^4.0.2",
    "azure-devops-ui": "^2.237.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.79",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.25",
    "base64-inline-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "globals": "^15.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "tfx-cli": "^0.17.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

vss-extension.json
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "id": "<publisher>-mre-dev",
  "name": "DevOps Extentsion MRE",
  "publisher": "<publisher>",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "MRE for Devops Extension",
  "public": false,
  "categories": ["Azure Boards"],
  "targets": [
      {
          "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
      }
  ],
  "demands": [
      "api-version/3.0"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "default": "static/images/logo.png"
  },
  "scopes": [
      "vso.work_write"
  ],
  "contributions": [
    {
        "id": "extension-mre",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-page",
        "description": "MRE for the DevOps Extension",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": "MRE",
          "uri": "dist/page/page.html"
        }
    }
  ],
  "files": [
      {
          "path": "static",
          "addressable": true
      },
      {
          "path": "dist",
          "addressable": true
      }
  ]
}

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}

webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const entries = {};
const srcDir = path.join(__dirname, "src");

fs.readdirSync(srcDir)
  .filter(dir => fs.statSync(path.join(srcDir, dir)).isDirectory())
  .forEach(dir => (entries[dir] = "./" + path.join("src", dir, dir)));

module.exports = {
  target: "web",
  entry: entries,
  output: {
    filename: "[name]/[name].js",
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    server: {
      type: "https"
    },
    port: 3000,
    static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    alias: {
      "azure-devops-extension-sdk": path.resolve(
        "node_modules/azure-devops-extension-sdk"
      )
    }
  },
  stats: {
    warnings: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "azure-devops-ui/buildScripts/css-variables-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "base64-inline-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [
        { from: "**/*.html", context: "src" },
        //{ from: "azure-devops-extension-sdk/*.js", context: "node_modules"}
    ]
  })]
};


Hi there, Welcom to SO. Are you referencing any document to create a sample extension? If you are testing with the sample code in an official document, can you please share the link? Or, if you are building your own code, please also share a minimal reproducible example with the detailed reproducing steps. Don't forget to remove any sensitive or private information such as token, password, certificate, IP etc. since the community is visible to public. Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Added some extra info, hope it helps.

Hi there, Thanks for the update. I have tested the steps in the guidance, and the extension works well. May I know if you could see the expected page when testing on local host? Would you try use the same contents as those in the home.html and homt.tsx files from that guidance? Thx

Hi there, it works on local host yes. I have tried updating the dependencies and the error message seems to be gone. Now I have the problem that the Page component from azure devops ui seems to not be accepting any children. Do you have any idea how I might fix this problem without changing the component itself, as that also seems to create problems too?

Hi there, Thanks for taking time to share the update and glad to the know the issue in this post was gone. For another problem, you may raise a new post with the issue details to engage the insights from the community experts. Thank you again for the sharing and efforts.
